# call c++ function with reference parameter from cli

Tags: c++-cli, pass-by-reference

The unmanaged function(pure c++, if that matters):

```
 void fooC(float& result);
```

I define the wrapper as (managed wrapper, c++\cli):

```
void foo(float% result) //managed interface, need to pass result back to caller
{
      fooC(???);//how to call unmanaged function?
}
```

how to pass reference parameter in the wrapper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't convert a tracking reference to an unmanaged reference or pointer.  The garbage collector would cause havoc when the passed float is a field in an object.  You'll need to use a temporary:

```
  void foo(float% result) { 
    float temp;
    fooC(temp); 
    result = temp;
  }
```